# Select an element added at runtime when intro is running

Tags: intro.js

I am using intro.js to show help on our sites.

Sometimes we take the user to a button and we expect him to click it, once he clicks it a new element is added at run time. This new element is the selector for the next step.

However when the user goes to the next step the newly added element is not highlighted although it can be visually seen in the page.

Please visit this fiddle. User will click the start intro button, then the button highlighted in the first step a new input field is added and ideally in the next step the new field should be highlighted.

https://jsfiddle.net/7aqzw0du/1/

HTML

```
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="startIntro();">
  Click Me to Start Intro
</button>
</div>
<div>
<button type="button" id="btnSelect" onclick="showInput();">
  Click Me to Show Input
</button>
</div>
<div id="inputDiv"></div>
```

Javascript, goes in head

```
var helpDialog;

function showInput(){   
    document.getElementById("inputDiv").innerHTML = "<input id='inputSelect' type='text'>";
  helpDialog.refresh();
}

function startIntro(){
     helpDialog = introJs();
        helpDialog.setOptions({
            steps: [
        {element:"#btnSelect",intro:"Please click here to show input"},
        {element:"#inputSelect",intro:"This is the input added at runtime"}
      ],
            showProgress: true,
            exitOnOverlayClick: false,
            showStepNumbers: false,
            keyboardNavigation: true
        });     
        helpDialog.start();
}
```

**NOTE:** Please note that I cannot use addStep as I have a library that fetches all the steps for a page from the server and starts intro. So I really do not know which step should be added later on.

Also the useCase is such that the pages are already built in a way where elements are added at run time so making them show or hide means going back to all screens are changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the documentation of Intro.js, the elements mentioned in the steps are just highlighted, but the transitions only happen by clicking  the next or previous button of the Intro dialog.

It also seems like if an element is mentioned in steps but does not exist at that time, intro does not highlight it.

I've edited your fiddle a little bit so I'm creating the text field in the beginning and setting it hidden.

`<div id="inputDiv">
  <input id="inputSelect" type="text" hidden>
</div>`

and to trigger the transition, I've just added the code in your showInput() function

`function showInput(){

    document.getElementById("inputSelect").removeAttribute("hidden");
    helpDialog.nextStep();
}`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7aqzw0du/12/)

I think if you want to add a totally new element instead of just hiding and showing it, you would have to [add a step](https://introjs.com/docs/intro/api/#introjsaddstepoptions) after creating the element, and then calling the `nextStep()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that but as you can see from my edit the list of steps is fetched once when the page is loaded so addStep is not an option for now. Also the page is already built in such a way that the elements are added at runtime so just showing / hiding them will mean changing the code at a lot of places.

Comment: Well I guess in that case, you would probably have to add some extra information to the steps array you're fetching from the server, and then based on that add an extra event handler which would change the element of a specific step if it is not present.
I've made a new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7aqzw0du/43/) which does something like that.